# C - How to print a string element in a pointer to struct?

Tags: c

I'm relearning linked list data structure and I stumbled upon this problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node{
    char url[50];
    struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;

void add_url(Node * h, Node * c, Node * n){
    Node * temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    printf("\nType or paste your URL: ");
    scanf("%s", temp->url);
    if(h == NULL){
        h = temp;
        h->next = NULL;
        c = h;
    }else{
        c->next = temp;
        c = c->next;
        n = c->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node * h = NULL; // head
    Node * c; // current
    Node * n; // next
    add_url(h, c, n);
    printf("%s", h->url);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output `NULL`? How exactly do you get a string input from a pointer to struct?

Comment: Did `h` ever _stop_ being `NULL` inside `main`? You know you only changed a local variable with the same name inside `add_url`, and that this didn't affect the local variable inside `main`? And you could easily verify this by examining your variables in the debugger?

Comment: `void add_url()` ==> `Node* add_url()` ... `return h;` ... `h = add_url(h, c, n);`

Comment: You need to either pass the *address* of the pointer, so the arg is `Node **h` so that the function can alter the variable in `main` instead of the *copy* of it that was passed, or, return and assign the new value.

Comment: But `h` _is_ a pointer. You passed the pointer by value. The value is `NULL`. If you want to change the value of the pointer, you need to pass a pointer-to-pointer `Node**`. Or, as already suggested, _return_ the new head pointer instead. Return values are generally better style than inout-parameters, if possible.

Comment: Create one function which allocates a new node and adds it to the list. Create another function which sets the data of a single node. Then take it from there. It doesn't make much sense to have a function which takes 3 unallocated nodes as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. I have added some checks to avoid segmentation fault (access violation), buffer overflow in scanf, initialized variables and the function now returns the new head (Could instead return current node).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node {
    char url[50];
    struct Node* next;
};
typedef struct Node Node;

Node *add_url(Node** h, Node** c, Node** n) {
    Node* temp;

    if ((h == NULL) || (c == NULL) || (n == NULL))
        return NULL;

    if ((temp = malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    printf("\nType or paste your URL: ");
    if (scanf("%50s", temp->url) != 1)
        return NULL;
    if (*h == NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        *h = temp;
        *c = *h;
    }
    else {
        (*c)->next = temp;
        *c = temp;
        *n = temp;
    }
    return *h;
}

int main() {
    Node* h = NULL; // head
    Node* c = NULL; // current
    Node* n = NULL; // next
    if (add_url(&h, &c, &n) == NULL) {
        perror("add_url failed: ");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s", h->url);
    return 0;
}
```